# How to manage public and private files using Unisharp laravel file manager?

Tags: laravel

I want to build a website to sell some files. I am using laravel filemanager. 
I use laravel filemanager to store and upload my photos in public folder. so it can be easily accessed by the end user.
However I need to store my products files in a private folder which I can be able dynamically link to it if the user purchase the file.
Can I use laravel filemanager for that purpose without losing the ability to manage images in public folder?

Comment: Yes you can (still characters left)

Comment: @thomas Can you please provide more information on "how to do that"?

Comment: Your question isn't a great fit for this site. Please first explain what you tried. It's as simple as not storing your secret files in your webroot to start.